# Overleaf allowing autocomplete for \ref commands outside of current file

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

I am using Overleaf and have a `main.tex` file which includes various `.tex` files. In each tex file, if I create a `\label`, the `\ref` command pulls up options for the reference which helps me massively, but only in the existing chapters/sections of the current file. It doesn't pull up all potential labels, for example outside of the current file. How can I achieve this/is it possible? Would be so helpful as remembering the exact name you gave to a reference in a different file is very difficult!

Comment: This is not supported on Overleaf yet, sorry!

Comment: OK. will leave this Q up as im sure people have this question!

Comment: That's funny! The behaviour you are requesting for is now default. I came here to see how to disable it :-)